# React JS: How to pass static files to front-end (Django, React, Webpack) + ( no loaders are configured for .MP4 files )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webpack

I'm using a combo of Django + react js + webpack to build my application and I'm still really green on react js and webpack so I have no clue how to host or pass the files to frontend.
So basically I don't pass the static files via django, and I don't have any configuration for static files in django. I'm trying to pass the static files which are in react js main directory.

This is my project structure:

[image: s]

And you can also see the webpack config that I have right now.

But my question is how do I have to pass static files to react js?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Video from '../videos/video.mp4';
import {
    HeroContainer,
    HeroBg,
    VideoBg
} from './HeroElements';

const HeroSection = () => {
    return (
        <HeroContainer>
            <HeroBg>
                <VideoBg
                    /*src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4" */
                    src={Video}
                    type="video/mp4"
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                    muted
                />

            </HeroBg>
        </HeroContainer>
    )
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states,  you don't have appropriate loader to import `mp4` files. You can save your videos in the [public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) and access them in your code. What you need is `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable whose value is managed by `react-scripts`.

```
<video width={320} height={240} controls>
  <source src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/movie.mp4'} type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```